# Pointwise and uniform convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^2 - n^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

We have f : $\mathbb{R}$ \ $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{R}$ ; $ x \mapsto \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^2 - n^2} $

We then have to prove that f is well-defined and continuous.

I wanted to prove that f is well defined by showing that f(x) converges to a real function for all x in $\mathbb{R}$\ $\mathbb{Z}$

Then since $\frac{1}{x^2 - n^2}$ is continuous, I just wanted to prove that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^2 - n^2}$ converges uniformly to f.

I have tried bounding the sum by another expression, but that didn’t work out. I don’t really know how to precede, so any help would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried the Weierstrass M-test?

Comment: For what it's worth, Mathematica tells me that
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac1{x^2-n^2} = \frac{\pi  x \cot (\pi  x)+1}{2 x^2}.
$$
This does not look like a continuous function to me, so the convergence most likely is not uniform.

Comment: Thank you ! This will already be useful